# how to check weather a div style property pointer event is none on the code behind side

Tags: html, asp.net, events

How to check whether a `DIV` style property pointer event is none in the code behind using `if  else` statement?

I have to store the value of 1 in a variable if the `DIV` pointer event property is set to `none` and 0 if it is set to `auto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used panel in place of DIV initially disabled later I enabled it on radio button check through java_ script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3Awindow.getComputedStyle) to get a CSS property value.

However it may be helpful for you to explain what the "code behind" is. Sounds like you might be working server side, so there may be more to it.

Comment: i want something like this:   if(DIV.style.pointerevent==none){string a=1;}else {a=0}

Comment: yes by code behind i meant the servcer side..cs side..sorry for being unmeaningful